# html array of input elements created dynamically not properly interpreted in PHP Serverside

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, serialization

I am creating html input elements dynamically using DOM CreateElement()

```
function createHtmlElem( elName , attri ){

    var el = document.createElement(elName);
    for( var key in attri ){
        val = attri[key];
        el.setAttribute( key , val );
    }

    return el;
}
```

I wanted to create the following html elements using `createHtmlElem( 'input' , {"name":"usernames[]"} )` and it works, i mean it creates HTML Elements on the page.

```
<input type="text" name="usernames[]" />
```

**the problem is on the serverside.**
i get the form serialised using jquery.serialize() and get it posted,
on the serverside

expectation is

```
[usernames] => Array
        (
            [0] => andrew
            [1] => arul
        )
```

But i am getting as

```
[usernames[]] => 'andrew'
[usernames[]] => 'arul'
```

I am totally confused, Its very much impossible when you create input array elements statically by putting the raw html and get it posted.

Answer (score 0):

I created a post_processing function to process the received array. Hope its useful for someone.

```
/**
 * [create_array description]
 * Convert Array 
 * arr = [
 *     'username_1'=>'John Deo',
 *     'address_1'=>'wuhan',
 *     'pin_1'=>'560093',
 *     'username_2'=>'Dennis',
 *     'address_2'=>'Hubei',
 *     'pin_2'=>'605110'
 * ];
 *
 * arr = [
 *     [1] => [
 *         'username' => 'John Deo',
 *         'address'  => 'wuhan',
 *         'pin'      => '560093',
 *     ],
 *     [2] => [
 *         'username' => 'Napoleon',
 *         'address'  => 'Karnataka',
 *         'pin'      => '605110'
 *     ]
 * ]
 * @param  [type]  $inp    [description]
 * @param  integer $nitems [No of Set of items, for this eg nitems = 2]
 * @return [type]          [Rearrange array as required]
 */
function rearrange_array( $input_arr , $nitems){
    //unset( $inp['donor_id'] );
    $n = count( $input_arr );
    $i = 0;
    //nitems is the number of items of objects or books
    for($i = 0; $i < $nitems ; $i++){

        $tmp = [];
        foreach( $input_arr as $k => $v ){
            $new_key = preg_replace("/_[0-9]/",'', $k);// getrid of the underscore and the number behind.
            $tmp[$new_key]=$input_arr[$new_key . '_' . $i];
        }
        $output_arr[$i]= $tmp;
    }

    return $output_arr;
}
```